# In Lua how can I reliably get real world results to arithmetic

Tags: lua

In Lua how can I reliably get real world results to arithmetic:

```
local result = (1.09891 - 1.09889);
print(result);

the result i get is
2.0000000000131e-05


real result i want
.00002
```

Comment: This is not specific to Lua. You'll get the same results in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the result value. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) for why the result is not exactly what you think it should be. But, if all you are worried about is how it looks when you print it to the screen, you can do things like:

```
print(string.format('%f', result))
0.000020

print(string.format('%.5f', result))
0.00002
```

to format the printing of the result to your liking.

See [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format) for more info on string.format, or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) for an explanation of the 2e-5 value if you're unfamiliar with scientific notation.